# ESP-IDF Eclipse Plugin - Getting Error At End of Build

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded, esp32, esp-idf

### THE ERROR

I am trying to add an external component to my ESP32 project but am getting a CDT error at the very end of the build process. I have been trying to diagnose the issue for quite awhile now and have not seen any similar issues online.

[image]

By checking the log file within the workspace metadata directory, the error seems to stem from this exception being thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 44, end 40, length 40
```

So there is a string somewhere that is failing a bounds check? I'm not too familiar with Java so I don't know.

### EXTRA INFO

The component I'm trying to add is: ubxlib

The ubxlib library is hosted on GitHub and can be found [here](https://github.com/u-blox/ubxlib/tree/master).

And the directions for adding the library can be found [here](https://github.com/u-blox/ubxlib/tree/master/port/platform/esp-idf/mcu/esp32), under the header '**Integration With Your Application**'.

I have successfully compiled, flashed, and ran basic code for the ESP32 using the ESP-IDF plugin. I can also successfully build, flash, and run code with the ubxlib library implemented from the command line tools (via idf.py build/flash). Which leaves me to believe my error stems from a conflict between the plugin and ubxlib...

**The CMakeLists.txt file for the project looks like this:**

```
# The following lines of boilerplate have to be in your project's
# CMakeLists in this exact order for cmake to work correctly
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS "../../ubxlib/port/platform/esp-idf/mcu/esp32/components")

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(Rover-Controller)
```

- The only difference between this cmake file and the default is the *set(EXTRA_COMPONENT...)* line

**Here is the log file for a "successful" build (there still seems to be errors, but it compiles/flashes fine..)**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.expressions 4 201 2023-09-21 20:13:31.514
!MESSAGE No property tester contributes a property org.eclipse.embedcdt.managedbuild.cross.core.isGnuMcu to type class org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: No property tester contributes a property org.eclipse.embedcdt.managedbuild.cross.core.isGnuMcu to type class org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtensionManager.getProperty(TypeExtensionManager.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.expressions.AndExpression.evaluate(AndExpression.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.RegistryPageContributor.failsEnablement(RegistryPageContributor.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.RegistryPageContributor.isApplicableTo(RegistryPageContributor.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.PropertyPageContributorManager.getApplicableContributors(PropertyPageContributorManager.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.PropertyPageContributorManager.getApplicableContributors(PropertyPageContributorManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.hasPropertyPagesFor(PropertyDialogAction.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.isApplicableForSelection(PropertyDialogAction.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.isApplicableForSelection(PropertyDialogAction.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.PropertiesActionProvider.fillContextMenu(PropertiesActionProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService$2.run(NavigatorActionService.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.addCommonActionProviderMenu(NavigatorActionService.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.fillContextMenu(NavigatorActionService.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager.fillContextMenu(CommonNavigatorManager.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.fireAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.handleAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager$2.menuShown(MenuManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4274)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1071)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_INITMENUPOPUP(Control.java:5140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4772)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1478)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2306)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5040)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.TrackPopupMenu(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu._setVisible(Menu.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runPopups(Display.java:4113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3654)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.expressions 4 201 2023-09-21 20:13:31.514
!MESSAGE No property tester contributes a property org.eclipse.embedcdt.managedbuild.cross.core.isGnuMcu to type class org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project
```

**And here is the complete log file of the unsuccessful build**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2023-09-21 20:16:36.835
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Building Rover-Controller
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration.build(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.build.CBuilder.build(CBuilder.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.AbstractCLaunchDelegate2$1.run(AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2402)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.buildProject(AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.buildForLaunch(AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.launchbar.ui.internal.commands.BuildActiveCommandHandler$1$1.run(BuildActiveCommandHandler.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 44, end 40, length 40
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4604)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2707)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2680)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration$CMakeIndexerInfoConsumer.getFileForCMakePath(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:1223)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration$CMakeIndexerInfoConsumer.acceptSourceFileInfo(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:1185)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.mergeResultsForFile(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.detectBuiltins(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.processJsonFile(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.parse(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:455)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration.processCompileCommandsFile(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:971)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration.runCmakeBuildCommand(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:436)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration.build(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:350)
    ... 17 more
!SUBENTRY 1 com.espressif.idf.core 4 0 2023-09-21 20:16:36.835
!MESSAGE Building Rover-Controller
!STACK 0
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 44, end 40, length 40
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4604)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2707)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2680)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration$CMakeIndexerInfoConsumer.getFileForCMakePath(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:1223)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration$CMakeIndexerInfoConsumer.acceptSourceFileInfo(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:1185)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.mergeResultsForFile(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.detectBuiltins(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.processJsonFile(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.parse(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:455)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration.processCompileCommandsFile(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:971)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration.runCmakeBuildCommand(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:436)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration.build(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.build.CBuilder.build(CBuilder.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.AbstractCLaunchDelegate2$1.run(AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2402)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.buildProject(AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.buildForLaunch(AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.launchbar.ui.internal.commands.BuildActiveCommandHandler$1$1.run(BuildActiveCommandHandler.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
!SUBENTRY 1 com.espressif.idf.core 4 0 2023-09-21 20:16:36.835
!MESSAGE Building Rover-Controller
!STACK 0
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 44, end 40, length 40
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4604)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2707)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2680)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration$CMakeIndexerInfoConsumer.getFileForCMakePath(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:1223)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration$CMakeIndexerInfoConsumer.acceptSourceFileInfo(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:1185)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.mergeResultsForFile(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.detectBuiltins(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.processJsonFile(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.jsoncdb.core.CompileCommandsJsonParser.parse(CompileCommandsJsonParser.java:455)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration.processCompileCommandsFile(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:971)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration.runCmakeBuildCommand(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:436)
    at com.espressif.idf.core.build.IDFBuildConfiguration.build(IDFBuildConfiguration.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.build.CBuilder.build(CBuilder.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.AbstractCLaunchDelegate2$1.run(AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2402)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.buildProject(AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.buildForLaunch(AbstractCLaunchDelegate2.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.launchbar.ui.internal.commands.BuildActiveCommandHandler$1$1.run(BuildActiveCommandHandler.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I'm just not even sure where I would begin to understand what exactly is going on. It's not the end of the world, I can still develop with the Eclipse plugin and build/flash with the terminal, it's just not exactly favorable.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**Edit: Other...**

I also think it is weird that I have multiple of the same static libraries after the build process. Surely this is not correct?

[image]

Comment: From the failure it looks like, there is a check in this eclipse plugin, if `begin` and `end` (addresses?) are ok. But in your case `begin = 44` and `end = 40`, so it might tell you, that the values are wrong because `begin > end`.